# Slow s3 url generating paperclip

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, string-interpolation

We are trying to optimize our views and on a page where 40 pictures are loaded with the following code :

```
= image_tag(product.pictures.first.data.url(:gallery))
```

We have a load time of 840ms, if we change it to the following code :

```
= image_tag("http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/products/#{product.pictures.first.id}/gallery.jpg?1325844462"
```

We become a load time of 220ms.

It means the interpolation of s3_path_url is very slow. Somebody else is expecting the same problems? For the moment I created a helper that generates my urls :

```
def picture_url(picture, style)
  "http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/products/#{picture.id}/#{style}.jpg"
end
```

Only problem I have here is that the cache key is not there and also the extension not.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? We are getting the same problem. We use expiring urls so can't hard code it like you did.

Comment: @nEEbz for the moment we did not find any solution. We use generate now our urls with custom helpers and it runs smoother.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm using helpers to generate my URLs now too.

Comment: Pagination with show more buttons?

Comment: Is there always just one image per product shown on this page?

Comment: My *guess* is the issue is with sql queries that each of those are running. In the first case, you're doing `product.pictures.first` which is happening 40 times, so probably n+1 queries here, while in the second case you're passing the picture directly and probably loading it more efficiently. Of course this is a guess and depends on your rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there always just one image of each product shown on the gallery page?

What about a cache column in your database. Whenever you create or update an image you could save this image_url as gallery_picture_url in your database and call it directly like

```
= image_tag(product.gallery_picture_url)

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit: :update_gallery_picture_url

  def update_gallery_picture_url
    self.update(gallery_picture_url: self.pictures.first.data.url(:gallery)) if self.gallery_picture_present?
  end

  def gallery_picture_present?
    (self.pictures.first.data.url(:gallery) rescue false).present?
  end
end
```